# Do you have to Export DLL's to move them to a different location?

Tags: vb.net, dll

I have a Visual Basic [DLL(Dynamic-link library)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) File (MyDLL_Core.dll) that I have updated and I want to move on a USB to a different computer (Just the `DLL`). I want to put the `DLL` in a `bin` folder of the other computer and run the program that uses the updated `DLL`. I am new to using `DLL`'s however when I move the new `DLL` and replace the old one it breaks the program. However, I think it's not due to code error (as it was a one line change). I looked up registering DLLs however I don't think my `DLL` is a `COM DLL`.

Do I have to Export DLL's to move them to a different location?

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try and Register the DLL... Entry point DLLRegisterServer not found

Comment: Check the properties that you have on the dll reference. `Specific Version` on the file should be set to false

Comment: If it's just a standard .NET DLL (not COM visible) then no, there's no need to register/export/deploy it.  Simply copying the file as you describe will work.  If it contains any breaking changes to the public interface, that obviously will fail when you try to run it, but as long as they are compatible, that's not a problem.  The only problem you're going to run into, as mentioned by @Jaxi is versioning.  If the assembly is signed, and that's changed, or the version number has changed and the consuming assembly is expecting a specific version, then that will cause a problem.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Thanks for your answer! the assembly info is the same in both, however it is still breaking my program..

Comment: What's the error it's showing?